# How can work be a function of position when non-conservative forces don't act the same way at each point?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, definition, conservative-field

My textbook and wiki/online articles all claim that work is given by the integral
$$W=\int_\gamma\vec{F}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\text{d}\vec{s}$$
where the $\text{d}\vec{s}$ is some infinitesimal step along the path gamma, and force is a function of position. This means, as a function of position, the force at every point in space is already predetermined. At any point, an object will always experience the same force.

However, consider a nonconservative force like friction. Clearly, if I push a point mass 10 units forwards and then 10 units back, it travels through the same position on its way back as forwards. However, the force of friction clearly reverses on the way back, contrary to the previously established fact work is given only as a function of position.

What am I misunderstanding?

Some thoughts I had are

- perhaps force as a function of position is only for conservative forces and my textbook and wiki/online articles are just incomplete or unclear in their phrasing?
- force maybe is a function of path instead of position? I don't know how to formally write this though.

Is there a clear formulation of work that is well defined for any path through 3D space for any force(s)? (ideally force would also be clearly expressed as a function of something like $\vec{F}(\text{something???})$)

Comment: Links to wiki/online articles?

Comment: I think you’re thoughts (the ones in bullets) are correct. From here https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/748400/346110 We can see that force in its most general form for any force nonconservative or conservative depends on both position and velocity. A conservative force is independent of velocity and only dependent on position.

Comment: Is it easier to understand if both force and path are parametrised, for example by a time parameter? Imagine a particle subject to a force that moves along some path over a time period. The integral says to add the product of whatever force is acting over a short time period by the length of the path over the same time period. The force dependence on position, speed, time itself, does not necessarily need to be known/predetermined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you accelerated your car on a straight   line from point  $~A=0~$ to  $~B=2~$  and back form B to A. What is the Work (Energy) that you need for it ?

The work is

$$W=\int \vec F\cdot\,\vec{dx}$$

with

$$\vec x= \left[ \begin {array}{c} s\\  0\\  0
\end {array} \right] 
\quad,\vec{dx}=\frac{\partial\vec x }{\partial s}\,ds=\left[ \begin {array}{c} 1\\  0\\  0
\end {array} \right]\,ds$$

assume conservative force

$$\vec F=\vec F(s)=c\,\begin{bmatrix}
  s^2 \\
  0 \\
  0 \\
\end{bmatrix}\quad\Rightarrow$$

$$W_{A\mapsto B}=\int_A^B c\begin{bmatrix}
  s^2 \\
  0 \\
  0 \\
\end{bmatrix}\cdot\,
\left[ \begin {array}{c} 1\\  0\\  0
\end {array} \right]\,ds=\int_{s(A)}^{s(B)}\,s^2\,ds=c\,\frac 83
$$

$$W_{B\mapsto A} \int_{s(B)}^{s(A)}\,s^2\,(-ds)= 
c\frac 83$$

hench $~W=2\,c\,\frac 83$

Which energy you need same case but with static friction force  $~F_\mu$

with
$$\vec F\mapsto \vec F-\vec F_\mu\quad,
\vec F_\mu=\mu\,m\,g\,\begin{bmatrix}
  1 \\
  0 \\
  0 \\
\end{bmatrix} \quad \Rightarrow\\
W=2\,W_{A\mapsto B}=2\,c\frac 83-4\,m\,g$$

general case the force

$$\vec F\mapsto  F(s(t)~,\dot s(t)~,t)\,\hat t\quad,
\vec{dx}=\frac{\partial\vec x }{\partial s}\,\frac{ds}{dt}\,dt$$

where $~\hat t~$ is the tangent of the path $~\vec x=
[x(s)~,y(s),z(s)]^T~$
$\Rightarrow$
$$W=\int_{t_0}^{t_1}  F(s(t)~,\dot s(t)~,t)\,\hat t\cdot
\frac{\partial\vec x }{\partial s}\,\frac{ds}{dt}\,dt\tag 2$$
or
$$\dot W=  F(s(t)~,\dot s(t)~,t)\,\hat t\cdot
\frac{\partial\vec x }{\partial s}\,\frac{ds}{dt}\tag 3 $$

to obtain the work W you need addition the equation of motion

$$m\,\ddot s= f(s(t)~,\dot s(t)~,t)\tag 4$$

solving eq. (3) and (4) you obtain the work W.

if you have the analytical solution of eq (4) $~s=s(t)~$ you can use eq. (2) to obtain the work W

---

s is the generalized coordinate on the path $~\vec x=\vec x(s)$

**Example**
[image]

The applied force $~F~$ move the  particle with the mass m on a circle path. Which energy (work) is needed , so the particle move  a distance of $~2\pi\,r~$

The position of the mass

$$\vec x(s)= \left[ \begin {array}{c} r \left( 1-\cos \left( {\frac {s}{r}}
 \right)  \right) \\ \sin \left( {\frac {s}{r}}
 \right) \end {array} \right]\quad\Rightarrow~,
\vec v=\dot s
 \left[ \begin {array}{c} \sin \left( {\frac {s}{r}} \right) 
\\  \cos \left( {\frac {s}{r}} \right) \end {array}
 \right]  
$$

form here

the kinetic energy
$$T=\frac{m}{2}\,\vec v\cdot\vec v$$
and the potential energy
$$ U=-m\,g\ ,r\sin \left( {\frac {s}{r}} \right)+(F_\mu-F)\,s$$

you obtain the EOM

$$ m\,{\ddot s}-mg\cos \left( {\frac {s}{r}} \right) -F+F\mu=0\tag A$$

where $~F_\mu=\sin \left( {\frac {s}{r}} \right) \mu\,mg~$ the friction force

the work differential equation is

$$\dot w=\,\left(F(s)+\sin \left( {\frac {s}{r}} \right)\mu\,m\,g\right)\,\dot s\tag B$$

solving eq. (A) and (B) ,with $~F(s)=c~$ and the initial conditions

$~[s \left( 0 \right) =0,\mbox {D} \left( s \right)  \left( 0 \right) =1
,W \left( 0 \right) =0]
~$

you obtain this result

[image]

you can see that to move the particle on the path , if you have friction you need more energy (Work) then with out friction.

Comment: Wait so the work integral in the end can be expressed as a time integral? with force as a function of position, velocity, and time?

Comment: This is correct

Comment: Thank you, I still don't completely get your answer, but I've mostly gotten the ideas down. I'll accept it now :)

Answer (score 0):

The magnitude of the frictional force depends on the relative motion between the two surfaces and acts in a direction so as to try and reduce the magnitude of the relative velocity.
Thus even if a body returns to the same location and the magnitude of the frictional force is the same the direction of that frictional force might have changed as the body is travelling in a different direction.

An example is the frictional force on a body due to the air when it is ascending and when it is descending.
Suppose the magnitude of the frictional force is $k\,v^2$ where $k$ is a positive constant and $v$ the speed of the body relative to the air.
Taking $\hat z$ as in the up direction the friction force on a body which is ascending is $-k\,v^2\,\hat z$ (downwards) and he friction force on a body which is descending is $k\,v^2\,\hat z$ (upwards).